# Errors importing SwiftyJSON with Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, swift, import, cocoapods, swifty-json

I was seeing how SwiftyJSON worked in a side project and wanted to move it over to my main project. After using Cocoapods to install SwiftyJSON and opening the xcworkspace (of my main project now), I went to add my code: `let jsonBIG = JSON(data: data2)` and was getting an error "Use of unresolved identifier JSON". I researched and found a solution saying to add `import SwiftyJSON` at the top of every file that uses it. When I do that, I get an error that says "No such Module 'SwiftyJSON'". I've looked all over and have tried these things and nothing has worked:

- cleaning and building project
- cleaning build folder
- rerunning pod install (with XCode completely closed)
- adding SwiftyJSON.framework to linked Frameworks and Libraries
- deleted xcworkspace file and reinstalled pod
- checked that my project's debug and release configuration are pointing to the configurations generated by the pod installation

I've looked through anything I could find on this topic on Google and StackOverflow and nothing seems to be working. I know its not a Cocoapods issue because I got SwiftyJSON to work on one of my other projects. Help?

edit:
Maybe this makes a difference? In my side project(where SwiftyJSON works) there is a yellow toolbox/ framework icon next to the framework:
[image]

But in my new project where I'm trying to get SwiftyJSON to work it is just a white library icon like this:
[image]

Even though when I go to add the framework it shows the yellow toolbox/framework icon like this:
[image]

Comment: Are your project's debug and release configuration in Xcode pointing to the configurations generated by the pod installation? Also, make sure you're using the `.xcworkspace` file instead of your project's `.xcodeproj` file.

Comment: Yes I did check that as well (forgot to mention that!) and I have triple checked that I'm using .xcworkspace

Comment: What does your `Podfile` look like?

Comment: platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'agentclient' do
 pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
end
---It's the same format of podfile that I used to install SwiftyJSON on my other project

Comment: `platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'agentclient' do
 pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
end` 
with better formatting. sorry! new to stack overflow

Comment: i have the same problem what i do is adding SwiftyJSON in linked framework and library in project target-->General

Comment: @Coyote I already tried that- no luck

Comment: then i cleaned the project and it have worked

Comment: @Coyote after everything I try I also clean and try to build but nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there were other errors that needed to be fixed in my project that were blocking SwiftyJSON from importing correctly. Once I fixed the other errors everything worked as expected.